# adding an edge does not change the isochrone in osmnx and networkx

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I try to create a new edge for a graph from OpenStreetMap and then perform an isochrone calculation.
I first download the graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

point = 45.45272, 9.17717
dist = 1000
network_type = "all"
trip_times = [5]  # in minutes
travel_speed = 5  # walking speed in km/hour

G = ox.graph_from_point(point, 
                            dist=dist, 
                            network_type=network_type, 
                            simplify=False)
```

Then I add an edge to the graph to connect two nodes:

```
graph_gdf_nodes = ox.utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=True, edges=False, node_geometry=True, fill_edge_geometry=False)
graph_gdf_edges = ox.utils_graph.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, edges=True, node_geometry=False, fill_edge_geometry=True)
graph_gdf_nodes = graph_gdf_nodes.set_crs('epsg:4326')
graph_gdf_edges = graph_gdf_edges.set_crs('epsg:4326')

x1, y1 = 9.1771815, 45.4527149
x2, y2 = 9.1769116, 45.4524742
new_line = LineString([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)])

bridge = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': [new_line]})
bridge['length'] = 34
bridge['highway'] = 'footway'
bridge['reversed'] = 'true'

desired_index = [(3517356820, 1028444115, 0)]
bridge.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(desired_index)

new_edges = pd.concat([graph_gdf_edges, bridge])
graph_new = ox.utils_graph.graph_from_gdfs(graph_gdf_nodes, new_edges)
```

And calculate the isochrone:

```
G = graph_new

gdf_nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, edges=False)
x, y = gdf_nodes["geometry"].unary_union.centroid.xy
center_node = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, x[0], y[0])
G = ox.project_graph(G)

# add an edge attribute for time in minutes required to traverse each edge
meters_per_minute = travel_speed * 1000 / 60  # km per hour to m per minute
for _, _, _, data in G.edges(data=True, keys=True):
    data["time"] = data["length"] / meters_per_minute
    
# get one color for each isochrone
iso_colors = ox.plot.get_colors(n=len(trip_times), cmap="plasma", start=0, return_hex=True)

# color the nodes according to isochrone then plot the street network
node_colors = {}
for trip_time, color in zip(sorted(trip_times, reverse=True), iso_colors):
    subgraph = nx.ego_graph(G, center_node, radius=trip_time, distance="time")
    for node in subgraph.nodes():
        node_colors[node] = color
nc = [node_colors[node] if node in node_colors else "none" for node in G.nodes()]
ns = [15 if node in node_colors else 0 for node in G.nodes()]
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(
    G,
    node_color=nc,
    node_size=ns,
    node_alpha=0.8,
    edge_linewidth=0.2,
    edge_color="#999999",
)

# make the isochrone polygons
isochrone_polys = []
for trip_time in sorted(trip_times, reverse=True):
    subgraph = nx.ego_graph(G, center_node, radius=trip_time, distance="time")
    node_points = [Point((data["x"], data["y"])) for node, data in subgraph.nodes(data=True)]
    bounding_poly = gpd.GeoSeries(node_points).unary_union.convex_hull
    isochrone_polys.append(bounding_poly)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=isochrone_polys)

# plot the network then add isochrones as colored polygon patches
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(
    G, show=False, close=False, edge_color="#999999", edge_alpha=0.2, node_size=0
)
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color=iso_colors, ec="none", alpha=0.6, zorder=-1)
plt.show()
```

But the calculation seems to ignore the edge that I added, because the isochrone zone is the same as if I don't add that edge. The edge appears on the graph though. What did I do wrong?